# ¿Como puedo llamar a un DropDownList dentro de un Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Tengo en **Default.aspx** un gridview que contiene listas desplegables, en **Default.cs** no puedo utilizarlas, no me aparecen, es como si   no estuvieran. ¿Como las llamo?

Imagen de la mencion que hago.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La Estroctura en Default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No se han encontrado registros para mostrar."  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="auto-style5">
            <Columns>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Proyecto:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjgvw" runat="server" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged = "Filtro" AutoPostBack = "true"
            AppendDataBoundItems = "true">
            <asp:ListItem Text = "ALL" Value = "ALL"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("NameProj") %> 
        </ItemTemplate>           
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Ya me di cuenta que solo funciona cuando saco el Dropdownlist del Gridview, pero sinceramente lo quisiera dentro de la columna no afuera.

Comment: Procura dejar el código en lugar de las imágenes para que se nos facilite el poder ayudarte.

Comment: El `DropDownList` debe estar dentro del `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que debes de hacer es obtener la row en la que se encuentra el DropDownList:

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer, GridViewRow);
```

para luego poder buscar dentro de la row el contro anidado:

```
DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlProveedor"), DropDownList).DataSource=cmd.ExecuteReader();
DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlProveedor"), DropDownList).DataTextField = ""
DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlProveedor"), DropDownList).DataValueField = ""
```

Espero sea de Ayuda.

Comment: Amigo esta usando `C#` tu código es para `VB` antes de responder debes analizar la pregunta con detenimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es guardar la consulta en una variable fuera de la función a la cual puedas acceder para rellenar todos los `DropDownList` de la grilla sin necesidad de hacer una consulta para cada fila.

```
DataTable dtPrioridades = new DataTable();

private void FillPrioridadList()
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        sqlCon.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ddlPrioridad", sqlCon);
    dtPrioridades.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
}
```

Luego de eso te toca acceder los `DropDownList` de cada fila. Puedes hacerlo o bien recorriendo las filas con un `foreach` o con la función `RowCreated` del `GridView`. Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo pero lo importante es que debes recorrer fila a fila el `GridView`.

```
protected void grd_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlPrioridadgvw")).DataSource = dtPrioridades;
        ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlPrioridadgvw")).DataTextField = "P_Nivel";
        ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlPrioridadgvw")).DataValueField = "IdPrioridad";
        ((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlPrioridadgvw")).DataBind();
    }
}
```